# How can i disabled partially a input?

Tags: jquery

I would like to have only a part in my input disabled.
The input field is a subdomain, so i want something like this

xxxxxx.mydomain.com

Only the x must be editable, not the domain, is it possible?

Comment: why not make 3 separate input?

Comment: you can also use image.

Comment: or 3 separate input without border , but it depends on how you want to view all

Comment: Perfectly fine question. No reason to downvote. +1 to balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
$('input').on('focus',function(){
   return $(this).val($(this).val().split('.')[0]).select(); 
});
$('input').on('change focusout',function(){
    return $(this).val($(this).val() + '.mydomain.com');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m4hFM/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
<div class="domain">
    <input />
    <span>sometext.com</span>
</div>
```

then

```
.domain {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.domain input {
    padding-right: 100px;
}
.domain span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 3px;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8px8x/)

Answer (score 0):

Think you can use a textbox and  or , line them side by side

e.g

```
<div> <input type="" name="subdomain" id="subdomain"> <span id="domain">example.com</span></div>
```

You can then use javascript/jquery to get the domain name from the domain textbox and add it to the span, thereby making on the subdomain part editable.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

jquery mask plugin can help.

https://plugins.jquery.com/mask/

for example:

```
$('#inputid').mask('aaaaaaa.exp.com');
```